# javaee-api in jboss7.1.3 causing: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase

Tags: glassfish, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm currently trying to develop an ear app and would like to deploy it in jboss7.1.3 server.

I've use the jboss maven template to create a javaee6 ear app and replaced most of the javaee6 related dependencies with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Because I thought it would be better to stick with the standard. But when I add seam-faces  to the dependency an error was thrown:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018045: Failed to load annotated class: org.jboss.seam.faces.component.UIViewAction
```

Further digging revealed a missing class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase
```

Why is that? Should I just stick with the dependencies provided by the maven archetype? My concern is what if I migrate to Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above is valid but what I did was different, I removed the seam-faces dependency and it solved my problem. What I'm using from seam-faces is the s:objectConverter I've use in combo box, without it I created my own entity converter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, stick with what's in the archetype. The "standard" jars are not complete and iirc, were created with stripping out byte code unlike the way the Geromino and JBoss jars were created (someone going through the spec and hand coding all the apis). As long as you keep the jars as `provided` there shouldn't be any issue using Glassfish.